# Is_Integer returning incorrect result - Python 2.X

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

```
dig = 16807
digcount = len(str(dig))
minroot = dig ** (1 / float(digcount))

print minroot
print minroot.is_integer()
```

`minroot` returns as 7.0 as a float, but `is_integer` returns `FALSE`.

I tried `(7.0).is_integer()`, and it returns `TRUE`. What gives?

Comment: Python 2 rounds more aggressively when `print`ing floats.

Comment: `minroot` is `7.000000000000001` not `7.0` use `print repr(minroot)` to see the a better represented value

Comment: @MooingRawr wow that's correct... why the hell does it do that? the answer should be 7 even

Comment: @MooingRawr: Strictly speaking, not the exact value, but enough digits to distinguish the value from any other float.

Comment: @Alex: `minroot` is not an integer. In real-number arithmetic, it would be an integer, but true real-number arithmetic is unimplementable. This is floating-point, an approximation.

Comment: @user2357112 extract was a poor choice of word on my part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken more read here

Comment: what is the resulting type of an int divided by a float? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958684/python-division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNote that `minroot` is not *precisely* 7.0, due to floating-point imprecision.  `is_integer` requires that precision.  Here's your code, with a little more detail.

```
dig = 16807
digcount = len(str(dig))
minroot = dig ** (1 / float(digcount))

print repr(minroot)
print minroot.is_integer()
a = 7.0
print a, type(a)
print a.is_integer()
```

Output:

```
7.0000000000000009
False
7.0 <type 'float'>
True
```

---

**UPDATE: HOW TO HANDLE "VERY CLOSE"**

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558216/function-to-determine-if-two-numbers-are-nearly-equal-when-rounded-to-n-signific) for code to handle *almost* equal.  The general approach is to set a tolerance and use something such as:

```
if abs(a-b) <= tolerance:
```

Or, "is the difference too small to matter?"

Comment: I see. How do you deal with this in practice? I'd like to check if minroot is an integer in an `IF` statement I have

Comment: `is_integer` is not a type check; it's a value check.

Comment: @Alex: If properties like that are important to you, floating-point arithmetic is not suitable for your use case. Formulate your program in terms of types that provide exact operations, like ints, and consider getting a computer algebra system, like SymPy.

Comment: @user2357112; thanks for proofreading my brain.  I'm fixing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more exact decimal arithmetic, use the decimal module. Decimals do not have an `is_integer method`, but you can compare to the int value.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> 7**5
16807
>>> from decimal import Decimal as D
>>> n = D(16807)**(D(1)/D(5))
>>> n
Decimal('7.000000000000000000000000000')
>>> int(n)
7
>>> n == int(n)
True
```

To show that the test does what you want:

```
>>> m = D('7.000000000000000000000000001')
>>> m == int(m)
False
```

Comment: That only happened to work out nicely because 1/5 is exactly representable in decimal. For something like 729^(1/6), it fails again. You can't get exact results out of inexact arithmetic just by throwing more precision at the problem or changing the base.

Comment: You are right.  `729**(1/6)` calculated with binary floating point happens to be equal to int 3, while calculated with decimal floating point, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs "Return True if the float instance is finite with integral value, and False otherwise". Only zeroes in decimal places makes it return true as an integer.