# How to have an algorithm round in a "smart" way automatically

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

I would like to round number in a code but in a way that it adapts to each values.

For example i would like a rounding algorithm to return :

- 0.999999 it should return 1
- 0.0749999 it should return 0.075
- 0.006599 it should return 0.0066
  and so on ...

I don't know in advance the number of digits (which is kinda my problem)

I was thinking to use strings to find where are the 9s (or count the 0s) but it is quite a lot of effort for that i was thinking ?

If you know any way to do that (if possible without advanced libraries) i would appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to pick some number of digits. Like what if you had `0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007499`. Do you really want to keep all of those leading `0`s?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do?  Is this just for displaying a number in some printed output?

Comment: @pault Yeah it shouldn't go further than 10E-5.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Basically i'm trying to evaluate if A == B but during calculation python adds numerical error to A and at the end it is not equal to B (but it should be) because A = 0.074999 and B = 0.075 (if that makes sense?)

Comment: @BznTT seems like you should use [`math.isclose`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36407955/5858851)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to determine if two numbers are nearly equal when rounded to n significant decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558216/function-to-determine-if-two-numbers-are-nearly-equal-when-rounded-to-n-signific)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's some complicated. but, It works. Please make sure the result is what you want. I think you can understand how to round the number from code.

```
def clear9(numstr):
    liststr = list(numstr)
    for index in range(len(liststr)-1,-1,-1):
        if liststr[index] == '.': continue
        if liststr[index] == '9': 
            liststr[index] = '0'
            if index == 0:
                liststr.insert(0, '1')
        else: 
            if index != len(liststr)-1:
                liststr[index] = str(int(liststr[index])+1)
            break
    numstr = ''
    for item in liststr:
        numstr += item
    return numstr

def myround(num):
    numstr = str(num)
    numstr = clear9(numstr)
    return float(numstr)


print (myround(9.05))
print (myround(9.999999))
print (myround(0.999999))
print (myround(0.0749999))
print (myround(0.006599))
print (myround(0.00659923))
print (myround(0.09659923))
print (myround(-0.00659923))
```

```
9.05
10.0
1.0
0.075
0.0066
0.00659923
0.09659923
-0.00659923
```

Comment: It will probably be tricky to catch all the edge cases ie. `myround(9.05) == 0.0`

Comment: Thank you Yaho.   As Mark pointed out that is the main trouble with your method as i can have any number (such as 0.099649999) which makes it tricky

Comment: @BznTT  What number you should get by `0.099649999` ? `0.1` or `0.09965`?

Comment: @yahocho 0.09965 is the value i would like...    Maybe i should search for X consecutive "9s" to reduce the room for error ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

def round_(number):
    dist = int(math.log10(abs(number))) #number of zeros after decimal point
    return (round(number, abs(dist) + 2) if dist != 0 else round(number))

print(round_(0.999999))
print(round_(0.0749999))
print(round_(0.006599))
print(round_(-0.00043565))
```

output:

```
1
0.075
0.0066
-0.00044
```

Comment: it looks interesting but from what i understand you arbitrarily add "+2" to the number of digit rounded so it wouldn't be able to deal with a number like "0.074569999.." where i would like "0.07457" your code returned "0.075".. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: for examle if you want to get 0.07457 from 0.074569999, you will use :abs(dist) + 4, in this case 4 is number of digits which you are "observing" (after last 0 in decimal places)  @BznTT

Comment: Oh i see i think i can make it work with a small twist thank you !

Comment: @ncica @BznTT  `0.09659923` => `0.097`. I think It should be `0.09659923`.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with floating point numbers is tricky. You want to do a kind of round-off in base 10, but floating point numbers are base 2.

So I propose to use the `decimal` module, which can represent real numbers exactly, as opposed to base-2 floating point.:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def myround(num):
    dec = Decimal(num)
    adj = abs(dec.adjusted())+1
    return round(num, adj)
```

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.adjusted) for `Decimal.adjusted()` to understand how this works.

A test:

```
In [1]: from decimal import Decimal                                                                      

In [2]: def myround(num): 
   ...:     dec = Decimal(num) 
   ...:     adj = abs(dec.adjusted())+1 
   ...:     return round(num, adj) 
   ...:                                                                                                  

In [3]: myround(0.999999)                                                                                
Out[3]: 1.0

In [4]: myround(0.006599)                                                                                
Out[4]: 0.0066

In [5]: myround(0.0749999)                                                                               
Out[5]: 0.075
```

Comment: Hi, works great but doesn't seems to deal with numbers such as "0.1459999" where it returns "0.15" where i would like "0.146".
Also my end goal is to implement it out of python and i don't think i'll have access to the adjusted() method.